# Writing a Program that Print Out All Possible Monotonic Functions

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, computer-science

I am trying to write a program (via C++) that prints out all possible functions $f:\{1,...,m\}\to\{1,...,n\}$ such that if $i\leq j$ then $f(i)\leq f(j)$.

I am really confused because I am not sure if it is possible to write a program that could do so, since there is basically an infinite number of functions that satisfy such condition.  Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues on which the question is a bit unclear.

The first, and really crucial, issue is: which of the following three problems are you trying to solve?

1. Given $n,m$, write a C function **void monotone_n_m()** that prints all monotone functions $f:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,m\}$.
2. Write a C function **void monotone(int n, int m)** that, given $n,m$, prints all monotone functions $f:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,m\}$.
3. Write a(n infinite-loop) C function **void every_monotone()** that, for every $m,n$, and every monotone function $f:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,m\}$, eventually prints $f$.

The distinction between the three is really crucial. 1. is looking for a function that takes no input and runs for a given, fixed time. 2 is looking for a function that takes $(n,m)$ as input, and eventually terminates, but whose running time can be arbitrarily large for sufficiently large $(n,m)$. 3. is looking for a function that takes no input, *never* terminates, but just keeps spitting out monotone functions - and every monotone function with a finite domain will, sooner or later, be spit out, *even if there are infinitely many of them*. Let's tackle each of the $3$ problems in turn, below, after dealing with the second issue.

The second issue is: what do you mean by "print a function"? Do you mean print the C code that implements that function? In fact, this is not such a big deal, because any function $f:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,m\}$ is *essentially* an integer array a[] of size $n$, such that $f(i)=a[i-1]$ (and note that $f$ is monotone if and only if a[] is sorted, which can be easily checked with a single pass on it). It's not difficult to write a C function **void print_foo(int * a, int n)** that takes any such array a[] in input and prints another C function **int f(int i)** returning, on input $i$, $f(i)=a[i-1]$. So, we'll leave it at that, and assume that "printing a sequence of functions" really means "invoking **print_foo()** on a sequence of integer arrays". Let's dive into the $3$ problems.

---

1. This is easy. **void monotone_n_m()** has $n$ nested loops   for($i_1:1\to m$) $\dots$ for($i_n:1\to m$), and in the inner loop checks if the $n$ element array $a=[i_1,\dots,i_n]$ is sorted (meaning the corresponding function would be monotone); and if (and only if) a[] is sorted **print_foo(a,n)** gets called to print the corresponding function.

---

2. This is trickier, because in some sense, you need a program with a number of nested loops $n$ that depends on the input! C is not as friendly as other languages (e.g. Lisp!) for this stuff (C++ is somewhat better), but it's still quite doable, e.g. using recursion.  To this end, we can write a function **void rec(int n, int m, int $\ell$, int * a)** with a third argument $\ell$ that informally describes how deep in the nested loops we are (i.e. on which index of the array we are currently operating), and a fourth argument that is an integer array a[]; and simply have **monotone(n, m)** allocate a[], and then invoke **rec(n,m,0,a)**.

   Informally, **rec()** starts "positioned" on the first element of the array ($\ell=0$), and assigning to it in turn each value in $\{1,\dots,m\}$, calls itself to take care of the second element; then the third ... and so on. When the recursion reaches the last element, instead of **rec()** we invoke **print_foo()** (as in 1. above, if and only if a[] is sorted):

**void rec(int n, int m, int $\ell$, int * a)**:

for($i:1\to m$)
$\{$ $a[\ell]=i$;
if $(\ell<n-1)$ rec(n,m,$\ell+1$,a);
else if (a is sorted) print_foo(a,n);
$\}$

---

3. This looks hard, but it's actually very easy: you just have to create an infinite loop that, for every $(n,m)$ eventually calls **monotone(n, m)** (from 2. above). To enumerate every possible *pair* $(n,m)$, just consider every possible $sum\geq 2$, and split it into all the $(sum-1)$ possible pairs adding up to $sum$:

**void every_monotone():**

$sum\gets 2$;
repeat forever: $\{$for($i:1\to sum-1$) **monotone(i, sum-i)**; $sum\gets sum+1$;$\}$

---

Note that the code above is inefficient. Monotone functions can be a very small subset of all functions from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ to $\{1,\dots,m\}$, so enumerating all functions and then keeping only the monotone ones can be a huge waste; but it does make the code hopefully a bit easier to understand. To only enumerate monotone functions, instead of having each index range from $1$ to $m$, simply have it range from the value of the previous index (or from $1$ in the case of the first) to $m$.

Comment: Hmmm....I am asking about C++ domain.

Comment: @MathWanderer everything I wrote about C also applies to C++. With C++ you can do more things (e.g. instead of having a separate rec(), just write monotone(m,n) with two extra default arguments $\ell=0$ and $a=0$), including some slightly more sophisticated things like the use of iterators that would produce more elegant code, at the expense of being accessible to fewer readers. I think that, as it stands, the answer strikes a good balance between being "good" and being "accessible" to people without sophisticated programming backgrounds (this is *not*, after all, a website devoted to coding).

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the last condition, just counting the functions that go from {1,...,m} to {1,...,n}: there are n times m functions. For example, there are n functions for which f(x)=1, when x is not 1, there are another n functions for which f(x)=1, when x is not 1, but for which f(2)=2, and so on

Comment: What do you mean by it?  How can I determine all possible functions from n x m functions?

Comment: Sorry, the answer is $n^m$$

Comment: Yes, but still I am curious about it.

Comment: @lisyarus just showed you how to write the functions. Remember that you don't need an analytical form, but a tabular form. You don't care what the function is doing for numbers not in {1,...,m}. For example, say m=2, and n=1. You have $f(1)=f(2)=1$ as one function. I don't write it as $f(x)=1$ or $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)+1$ or any other form

Comment: Thank you.  Based on your explanation, I do not have to worry if the function is integer-valued function or not, right?  I was trying to think about some integer functions as both domain and range are composed of integers, but it seems that I do not have to worry about what function is doing for the numbers.

Comment: correct. The function is integer-valued in this particular case, but not necessary for this problem. The solution would work equally well for mapping to {1/3, 2/3, ..., m/3}

Answer (score 1):

First, note that there is a *finite* number of *all* posible functions from $\{1\dots m\}$ to $\{1\dots n\}$. So, the number of monotone functions is also finite.

Such a function is just a monotone sequence of numbers $1\dots n$ of length $m$. If you randomly pick up $m$ numbers and sort them, you get such a sequence; any sequence can be built this way. Thus, the problem boils down to listing all sorted $m$-element combinations of numbers from $1 \dots n$ with repetitions.

I'll show a possible way of listing this sequences, leaving the actual algorithm to you.

$$1\dots 1,1$$
$$1\dots 1,2$$
$$\dots$$
$$1\dots 1,n$$
$$1\dots 2,2$$
$$1\dots 2,3$$
$$\dots$$
$$1\dots 2,n$$
$$1\dots 3,1$$
$$\dots$$
$$n\dots n,n$$